# AttributeError: '<class 'discord.client.Client'>' object has no attribute 'get_massage'　[メッセージを取得したい]

Tags: python, python3, discord

[/meg [メッセージid] で取得したい！！]
python3[discord.py]でメッセージIDでメッセージなどを取得したいのですが分かりません
discord.py ver: 0.16.12

Error:

```
AttributeError: '<class 'discord.client.Client'>' object has no attribute 'get_massage'
```

Cord:

```
if message.content.startswith('/meg'):
    msg = await client.get_massage(message.channel, id)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "TEXT: {}".format(msg))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

打ち間違いです。`get_massage` ではなく `get_message` です。

Comment: 変更してみましたが....
/meg [メッセージid] でやっても..

Error:
```discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)```

Comment: @Blockgrass さん、それはまた別のエラーなので、別にご質問頂ければと思います。今回のエラーは「`'get_massage'` が見つかりません」というものです。